# Error - "Result consisted of more than one row", due to GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have following MYSQL Stored Procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DWH.product_stats(OUT int_return INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE vc_sku, 
      vc_prod_id    VARCHAR(100);

  DECLARE int_views,
      int_fav,
      int_month, 
      int_year, 
      not_found     INT DEFAULT 0;

 DECLARE cur_sku CURSOR FOR

 SELECT product_id, sku FROM product LIMIT 0,10;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = 1;

 OPEN cur_sku;
 REPEAT

FETCH cur_sku INTO vc_prod_id, vc_sku;
IF NOT not_found THEN
  -- Number of Views and Favs
  SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS views,
          COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type_id = 5 THEN 1 END) AS favs,
          MONTH(logged_at) AS log_mon, 
          YEAR(logged_at) AS log_year INTO int_views, int_fav, int_month, int_year
  FROM report_event
  WHERE object_id = vc_prod_id
  GROUP BY log_mon, log_year
  ORDER BY log_year, log_mon; 

  -- DEBUG
  SELECT vc_sku, vc_prod_id, int_views, int_fav, int_month, int_year ;
END IF;
UNTIL not_found END REPEAT ;
CLOSE cur_sku;

END;
```

if I run this normally, there are no errors. I get the results. But I use this in a MYSQL Stored Procedure. Then when I try to run the Store Procedure it gives me this error saying "Result consisted of more than one row". 
This is because I have a GROUP BY for month and year, which will generate more than one record for a product. But that's the functionality I want. 
What would be the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: What kind of procedure are you running it in? What are you trying to return from the SP?  This code _alone_ inside a procedure would be fine.

Comment: Ok, I just added the full SP. I will be writing the out put of this SQL to a temp table

Comment: You're missing the part of your declaration that provides the name of the SP, the parameters it accepts, and what it returns. At least one of those three items is kind of important to your question, I think.

Comment: It really doesn't take any param at the moment, I have a return param just for the sake of having one, it really doesn't do any thing, any way I have added the SP creation part as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think approach I took is totally wrong, since the second SQL return multiple rows, to do something with that results I need to have that as a cursor all together.  So I rewrote the SP as follows, and its working fine now,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DWH.product_stats;
CREATE PROCEDURE DWH.product_stats(OUT int_return INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE vc_sku, 
      vc_prod_id    VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE not_found INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur_sku CURSOR FOR
  SELECT product_id, sku FROM product LIMIT 0,10;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = 1;

OPEN cur_sku;
REPEAT
  FETCH cur_sku INTO vc_prod_id, vc_sku;
  IF NOT not_found THEN
  SET @vc_prod_id = vc_prod_id;
  -- Number of Views and Favs
  BEGIN
    DECLARE int_views,
            int_fav,
            int_month, 
            int_year INT;

    DECLARE not_found_ev INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cur_event CURSOR FOR
      SELECT  
        COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS views,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN event_type_id = 5 THEN 1 END) AS favs,
        MONTH(logged_at) AS log_mon, 
        YEAR(logged_at) AS log_year 
        FROM report_event
        WHERE object_id = @vc_prod_id
        GROUP BY log_mon, log_year
        ORDER BY log_year, log_mon;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found_ev = 1;  

      OPEN cur_event;

      report_event_loop : LOOP 

        FETCH cur_event INTO int_views, int_fav, int_month, int_year; 
        IF not_found_ev THEN
          CLOSE cur_event;
          LEAVE report_event_loop;
        END IF;
        -- DEBUG
        SELECT @vc_prod_id, vc_sku, vc_prod_id, int_views, int_fav, int_month, int_year ;
      END LOOP;
      SET not_found_ev = 0;
  END;
 END IF;
 UNTIL not_found END REPEAT ;
 CLOSE cur_sku;
END;
```